# dynamic name textarea with razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, ckeditor

I am working with ckeditor and I need to load multiple instances so each of them needs a different name otherwise it wont work. Now I am trying to make the names dynamicly so they always have a different name. For the name I want to add a string and integer together where the string is simply editor and the integer is an id of my model. I have the name of the ckeditor already dynamic but I cant get the name of the textarea dynamic.

**Here is the dynamic named ckeditor**

```
  @*CKEdito script*@
  <script>                                         
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor'@(messages.MessagesId);
  </script>
```

**Here is the Textarea that I dont get named dynamicly**

```
@Html.TextArea("editor", htmlAttributes: new { name = "editor1", id =
"editor"})
```

**I have already tried this**

> @Html.TextArea("editor@(message.MessagesId)",

**Or this**

> @Html.TextArea("editor"@message.MessagesId,

Both dont work I would like to know if it even is possible and if so how.

Comment: Are you using a Model? How are you invoking it? You can try using a List of model and iterating through each model id.

Comment: @lloyd this is placed in a foreach statement so it should get the id of the message of the model its more the syntax that is strange to me. Why does it work at the name of the ckeditor but not at the textarea

Comment: I would make sure your replace method is inside a `$document.ready()` method or `CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function() { your code });` Just in case the script is running before the elements have fully loaded.